# Bind Combobox to ArrayList WPF C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is it possible to bind a combobox to an ArrayList that is holding object? I have seen so many examples but nothing that is directly using an ArrayList

My Object class has properties Id, Name, Value, Text, Data, etc.

```
obj1 = new Object()
obj2 = new Object()
obj3 = new Object()

ArrayList() list = new ArrayList()
list.Add(obj1)
list.Add(obj2)
list.Add(obj3)
```

I'm setting this to the `ComboBox.ItemsSource`

```
combo.ItemSource = list
```

And my ComboBox contains this XAML

```
DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=Id}"
```

This appears to work, but it displays the entire object as a "string" instead of just the `Id`

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What did you expect it to be displayed as? What does your actual model class look like? If you don't tell it otherwise, it will just call the `ToString()` method on your object and just return the object type as a string.

Comment: You tried setting the DisplayMemberPath and... what?

Comment: Mr. Burland has identified exactly what I am seeing, it is calling my .ToString() method. Is there a way I can just display the Id from the object?

Comment: I guess I was making this overly complicated. The problem is I was using DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=Id}" and all I had to do was DisplayMemberPath="Id", I am not sure which answer to accept.

Answer (score 1):

`DisplayMemberPath` is meant to be a string containing the property name that you want to display.

It is a shortcut for telling the ComboBox to render each item as

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayMemberPathValue}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

For example, if set set

```
DisplayMemberPath = "Id"
```

Then it will render as

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
```

What you have now is telling WPF that obtain the `DisplayMemberPath` property from `ComboBox.DataContext.Id`, which is most likely invalid so you should just get a binding error.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the type from object to your complex type.

system.object does not have id property. so it cannot render that.

if your items source is array list of complex type instead of just int or string what you need to do is:

```
public class Person 
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

If you change your type your bindings and all should start working properly.